# Vocal recording sounds like two voices. Can it be removed?

Tags: microphone, audio-recording, vocals, distortion

A vocal recording I made for a gaming let's play somehow sounds like 2 voices are going at the same time. It sounds robotic and extremely annoying, and I don't know how it happened, since my microphone does not usually sound like this. Is there any way I can fix this? I have access to Audacity and Adobe Creative Cloud if that helps.

Here's a [10-second sample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12yG7uRzkNoZe5UAitsdNvs4_WNaVmE9D/view?usp=sharing) to show you what I mean. I can upload the full recording if needed.

Comment: I get a "You need access" message. Could you make the sample file public?

Comment: Sorry about that, should be public now

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to hear the sound file, I'm going to assume your recording has taken the usual input via mic, plus the same again through some internal or external route very slightly delayed.

If that is the case then no, there is no way to fix it. Like most issues where you have additional voices, you'll have to re-record.

Comment: I just fixed the access on the sound file, though you're probably right about it.

Answer (score 0):

You say your mic does not "usually sound like this." In the clip you are speaking in an animated and loud voice. Could it be room reverb? Is the mic near hard reflective surfaces? Does the duplicate effect go away at lower volumes or softer tones?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [Comb Filtering](https://www.izotope.com/en/learn/what-is-comb-filtering.html) due to reverb. This isn’t something that’s easy to fix, and even if you do it probably won’t sound as good as a clean recording.

[Absorption and diffusion](https://splice.com/blog/acoustic-treatment-home-studio-budget/) will help. Make sure you place the mic in a good position according to its [polar pattern](https://www.shure.com/en-US/performance-production/louder/microphone-directionality-polar-pattern-basics) to minimize how much reverb it records.